# batch - refer to CSV and have an if statement check against for target text

Tags: csv, batch-file, if-statement

I have a simple batch where it echos each cell from a CSV file.
I would like to have an 'IF' statement to check if current cell value is one I need. So far I have:

```
@echo off

for /f "usebackq tokens=1-4 delims=," %%a in ("C:\Users\Name\New folder\Test.csv") do (

echo "%%a"
if %%a="computer123" echo "We need you"

pause
```

Comment: `if %%a="computer123"` --> `if "%%a"=="computer123"`

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't asked a question, I can only assume that there is a problem with what you have so far.

Here's what I have:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=1-4 Delims=," %%A In (
    "C:\Users\Name\New folder\Test.csv"
) Do (
    Echo="%%~A"
    If /I "%%~A"=="computer123" Echo="We need you"
)
Timeout -1
```

This of course assumes that you're looking for the content in the first field and you still wish to use fields 2, 3 & 4; *(Tokens 2[%%B], 3[%%C] & 4[%%D])*.

Comment: Apologies - Yes I meant to ask a question :) Thank you. This is great

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct, it helps future users of the site and motivates responders to provide their help.